# how to get responsive equal borders with imgs?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

[image: Borders]

This is what I Tried, but the borders are not equal.

```
.foo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #999;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
img{
    width: 47%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="foo">
    <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/z632s2x1z/shark.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/z632s2x1z/shark.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/z632s2x1z/shark.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/z632s2x1z/shark.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/07Lwwmgb/

or maybe my approach is bad

Comment: Actually it's fluid, equal borders. Responsive is associated, generally, with media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/n64vaahu/**

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.foo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #999;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: .5%;
}
img {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: .5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clear {
    clear: both
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo">
    <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/z632s2x1z/shark.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/z632s2x1z/shark.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/z632s2x1z/shark.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/z632s2x1z/shark.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```